# .NET code adds a trailing 0 to the numbers with 1 or 3 fractional digits stored in Oracle DB

Tags: .net, oracle, ado.net, oledb, odp.net

I run a SELECT query in .NET (using OracleDataAdapter) and SQL Developer. Result sets are slightly different:

**SQL Developer returns:**

[image]

**.NET returns:**

[image]

As you see, there is an extra 0 at the end of the values that have 1 or 3 digits after dot. What is the root cause of this problem and how to prevent it?

We can easily remove the extra 0 in code but we would like to prevent it by fixing the underlying issue. Thanks!

**UPDATE (1/29/2018):**

Data type in Oracle: 
[image]

This is the .NET code to fetch the data:

```
OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString);

if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
    conn.Open();

DataSet hereDataSet = new DataSet();

try
{
    using (OracleCommand oCmd = new OracleCommand())
    {
        oCmd.Connection = conn;
        oCmd.CommandText = "select V_COLUMN from T_TABLE where V_COLUMN='123'"; 

        OracleDataAdapter oDataAdapter = new OracleDataAdapter(oCmd);

        oDataAdapter.SelectCommand = oCmd;
        oDataAdapter.Fill(hereDataSet);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // exception logic
}
finally
{
    if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    { conn.Close(); }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem? trailing zeros after the decimal point have no mathematical meaning. What data type do you use in Oracle? What data type do you use in .Net? How are you viewing the results? (It might be as simple as wrong string format...)

Comment: I have added information about data type and .NET code. I show the results in a gridView. When I debug it, I see trailing zeros in the data set so It's not related to gridView or how I show the data... and yes, It's a problem as my business users don't want to see extra zeros even though they don't have mathematical meaning. We would like to remove these zeros by figuring out the root cause instead of removing them in .NET

Comment: I'm an SQL Server guy myself, the oracle data type doesn't mean much to me. The .Net data type, on the other hand, is interesting. If it's a [`decimal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal(VS.80).aspx) it would explain why you see trailing zeros.

Comment: What are PNG, POL, SEN & TUN? If they are values for another column then you haven't shown where you are selecting it which leads me to think that the posted code does not correspond to the code you are using. Also, have you tried putting a format string on the Data Grid View Column?

Comment: @Ciarán I have edited the query to remove column names. PNG, POL, SEN, TUN come from another column in the select statement. So the query would be "select V_COLUMN1, V_COLUMN2 from T_TABLE where V_COLUMN='123'"... As I mentioned in the question, there are ways to format the string after receiving it from Oracle but we are trying to figure out why we receive an extra zeros from the database

Comment: You are not. It's just being formatted that way.

Comment: @Ned https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZdBiYT , .NET does not add any trailing zeros by default, it looks like your logic displaying value adds it, what kind of application do you have? Desktop (Forms/WPF) or Web ?

Comment: @AkashKava Thanks for your example. I think OracleDataAdapter is somehow adding these trailing zeros in my case

Comment: It has nothing todo with Oracle. It's just how .net handles decimals. A decimal has great significance. Ex. 1.2 is less accurate than 1.20 because 1.2 can be in the range 1.15 - 1.25. You could cast the decimals to float's or doubles to get rid of the trailing zeroes.

Comment: @Gnor, as per my observation, trailing zeros are added by OracleDataAdapter which is developed by Oracle. Even though Oracle DB doesn't have these zeros, OracleDataAdapter is adding them once the data is fetched from DB. There are ways to remove them but I was just trying to make sure the root cause through this topic. It looks like everybody agrees on that this is how the ODP.NET is designed. Btw, it's WebForms application Akash

Comment: I am sending a support request to Microsoft. FYI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a support ticket to Oracle. They told me that it is a BUG

Comment: Thanks for confirming Ned.

Answer (score 2):

As per the MSDN documentation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd.aspx

> If format is null or an empty string, the return value of this instance is formatted with the general numeric format specifier (G).

I think what you want to do is:

```
var asExpected = oracleDataReader.GetDecimal(0).ToString("G0");
```

Comment: So do you think this issue is caused by the implicit conversion process of ODP.NET? Because we are not explicitly converting decimals to string as you will notice it in our code... There are ways to remove these trailing zeros as you mentioned one of them, we want to find the root cause

Comment: Hi Ned, Sorry for taking 5 months to get back to you. I've just added ODP.Net support for an app I manage, it uses a Factory pattern for its DAL, it's a 31 yrs old app. So I've added odbc, then OleDb, and now ODP.net, everytime there's nuances like this. It's always to do with **Decimal**, because MS and Oracle use different types. The problem first existed in .net 1.1 and there were minor fixes in .net 2. Though with the ODP.net it's much less forgiving than OleDB, I cast all NUMBERS(9) to string then back to Decimal. I made a note of this in the source code, I'll post the link on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle stores numbers differently.   Are you sure that the number you are getting back from oracle when going to .net decimal isnt 33641.70000000000001 for example.   You might want to get one row with a debugger into a regular variable and hover over it (not ToString) to find out...if that is it, your solution since you want only 3 decimal places would be to explicitly round to 3.   I've had to do this before.

Comment: It's a good point but it's not the case in my situation. I checked the values by hovering over hereDataSet in debugging mode (The screenshot in my question is from hereDataSet). Additionally, I queried DB in SQL Developer and confirmed the value